# Can I configure GitHub to trigger an email, tweet, or other event when a new release is published?

Tags: github, account-management, automation

I would like to send notifications to a specific set of users when a new version of our software is released.

People who 'watch' the repository get notifications for releases from GitHub, but I would like to send a notification to a custom list that includes people who don't use GitHub. Although the [notifications API is well documented](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/), it is unclear what my options are, or if such a feature has been developed by a third-party.

Is it possible to configure GitHub to trigger an email when a new release is published?

---

note: I found this [question addressed on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839622/notifications-for-new-github-project-releases), where it had been closed as off topic and remains unanswered.

Comment: You want a notification, but you already get notifications that get lost among all the other notifications? I'm lost.

Comment: @Wutnaut I want to be able to send notifications via email to specific users, independent of whether they 'watch' the repository, and with the capacity to customize the subject line and contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Service

There is some basic Github/Twitter integration in standard Github Services.

Go to repository settings. Select `Webhooks/Services` from menu on left. There using `Add Service` drop-list button you can add `Twitter` service.

Configuration is minimal, and twit is created for almost every commit, but it might be just enoug.

And there is similar thing for Emails.

#### Webhook

You could add your own [Webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

In few words, you can make github to send some data to external system (could be your custom server).

#### Zapier

[Zapier](https://zapier.com/) provides integration between many services, including [github-twitter](https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/twitter/1662/tweet-from-github-commit/) and [github-email](https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/) and [many more](https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/).